# Borrar todo después de ciertos caracteres

Tags: java, archivo, if, .asmx, while

Hola buenas tardes no se si no formule bien mi pregunta o si no esta hecha aun, pero aqui voy.
Estoy realizando un programa en JAVA que como tal revise un archivo de texto que contiene instrucciones en ASM sin embargo lo que yo busco como tal es borrar ciertas partes del codigo ASM no toda la linea, Me explico.
tengo este codigo:

```
; ===== CONTROL THE TRAFFIC LIGHTS =============================

    CLO     ; Close unwanted windows.
Start:
            ; Turn off all the traffic lights.
    MOV AL,0    ; Copy 00000000 into the AL register.
    OUT 01      ; Send AL to Port One (The traffic lights).
            ; Turn on all the traffic lights.
    MOV AL,FC   ; Copy 11111100 into the AL register.
    OUT 01      ; Send AL to Port One (The traffic lights).
    JMP Start   ; Jump back to the start.
    END     ; Program ends.

; ===== Program Ends ==========================================

    YOUR TASK
    =========
    Use the help page on Hexadecimal and ASCII codes.
    Work out what hexadecimal numbers will activate the
    correct traffic lights. Modify the program to step
    the lights through a realistic sequence.
```

y lo que deseo es borrar todo rastro de comentarios, esto con el fin de limpiar el código original y que quede de la siguiente manera:

```
CLO     
Start:
MOV AL,0    
OUT 01      
MOV AL,FC   
OUT 01      
JMP Start   
END
```

tengo parte de mi código java que ya realiza la funcion de limpiar algunas lineas, sin embargo la parte que se me esta dificultando es la que debo borrar el resto de la linea despues de encontrar un **";"** y un **"END"** que son precisamente los que marcan el inicio de un comentario y el fin del código.
ahora la parte de código que limpia es la siguiente:

```
while((linea=br.readLine())!=null){
    linea = linea.trim();
        if(linea.length()>0){
            if(!linea.startsWith(";")){
                System.out.println(linea);
                pw.println(linea);
            }
            if(!linea.contains(";")){
                pw.print("");
            }
        }
}
```

sin embargo no se que es lo debo hacer para eliminar el resto. tengo la idea de que es con esta parte del codigo que dicta:

```
if(!linea.contains(";")){
    pw.EliminaContenido;
}
```

Espero alguien me pueda orientar. muchas gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si la linea contiene `;`, no tenes que eliminarla, si no que tenes que cortar del ; en adelante. Muy diferente es si la linea empieza con un `;`, porque en ese caso si tenes que eliminarla.

Exactamente, el codigo que muestras

```
if(!linea.contains(";")){
    pw.EliminaContenido;
}
```

es donde esta tu problema. Si la linea contiene `;`, pero no empezo con `;` (que es lo que eliminaste antes), entonces deberias hacer un substring de la linea, quedandote con todo lo anterior al `;`.

Sin embargo, tu codigo tiene un if, y el siguiente no esta anidado, por lo cual, va a hacer las dos revisiones al mismo tiempo, y la linea va a quedar como erronea.

tu codigo deberia quedar algo asi:

```
if(linea.length()>0){
    if(!linea.startsWith(";")){
        System.out.println(linea);
        pw.println(linea);
    }
    else
    {
        if(!linea.contains(";"))
        {
        pw.print(linea.substring(0,linea.indexof(";")));
        }
    }
```

y como tarea para el hogar, si la linea contiene END solamente (comienza con END), deberías salir del while, ya que no hay nada mas que procesar.

Answer (score 1):

Hola convendria usar `String.indexOf()` si devuelve -1 el caracter no esta en la linea osea no hay comentario, y despues es solo obtener una cadena mediante `String.substring()` por lo que cambiaria:

```
if(!linea.contains(";")){
    pw.EliminaContenido;
}
```

a

```
if (linea.indexOf(";") != -1) {
    linea = linea.substring(0, linea.indexOf(";"));
}
```

Comment: agrego un extra, se deberia hacer una comparación adicional sobre la linea usando ```String.trim()``` para verificar que la linea resultante no sean espacios en blanco, se puede dar que por omisión el primer caracter sea un espacio por ejemplo y recien el segundo sea el punto y coma lo que matarias todas las validaciones anteriormente formuladas. y devolveria una linea vacia (un solo caracter pero es un espacio o una tabulacion.)

Answer (score 1):

Como opción puedes usar un método que elimina lo que se encuentra después del carácter especificado, en este caso `","`, este método buscaría la posición del carácter y y obtendría únicamente el texto desde el inicio hasta el carácter:

```
private static String eliminaContenido(String text, String sep){     
     if (text != null && text.contains(sep)) {     
         int position = text.indexOf(sep);
       text = text.substring(0, position +1);              
     }
     return text;
    }
```

Como ejemplo, lo llamarías de esta forma especificando el texto y el carácter que determina el final del texto necesario:

```
eliminaContenido("Valdemar Allan Poe; en StackOverflow.com", ";");
```

este método obtendría el valor:

```
Valdemar Allan Poe;
```

---

Aplicado a tu código sería de esta forma:

```
while((linea=br.readLine())!=null){
    linea = linea.trim();

     linea =  eliminaContenido(linea, ";"); //***

       /* if(linea.length()>0){
            if(!linea.startsWith(";")){
                System.out.println(linea);
                pw.println(linea);
            }
            if(!linea.contains(";")){
                pw.print("");
            }
        }*/
}
```